# Slide down description in list on hover with a delay jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of products in a grid. When you hover over the result, after a short delay, I'd like to slide down the description to show more information. Now I have some working code, but there is side effects. With the code below, when you take your mouse and quickly over over all of them, it tiggers the delay then shows all of the ones you've hovered over. Now because your mouse is no longer on the result, it doesn't hide them because there is no mouseout. What I'd like to do is only show them if the mouse still remains on them after the delay and slide backup on mouseout. Could someone help me tweak this code so that it works properly?

```
 <div class="listing">
     Title 1
     <div class="offer">
           offer 1
          <div class="invisibleAfterLayer">description 1</div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="listing" style="margin-top:10px">
     Title 2
     <div class="offer">
         offer 2
          <div class="invisibleAfterLayer">description 2</div>
     </div>
 </div>

    .invisiblelayer{display:none}

    $('.invisibleAfterLayer').addClass("invisiblelayer");

    $(".listing").on('mouseenter', function () {
        var parent = $(this);

        setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.offer .invisibleAfterLayer ', $(this)).slideDown();
        }, delay);
    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        $('.invisibleAfterLayer').slideUp();
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nbdpbes0/

Comment: You read my mind, I just added some html

Comment: You know you're missing quotes in your HTML ?

Comment: And try this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/uckbm784/**

Comment: Sorry, I was just manually writing  it up, I also added a jsfiddle. I'll look at yours now.

Comment: Your example doesn't appear to be working, take a look at my jsfiddle and you'll have a better idea what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Junkie, I think you need to set clearTimeout in order to make this code work properly.

```js
var t;

$(".listing")
.on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    t = setTimeout(function() {
      $this.find('.invisiblelayer').slideDown("slow");
      }, 1500);
        
}).on('mouseleave', function() { 
     clearTimeout(t);
     $(this).find('.invisiblelayer').slideUp("slow"); 
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aysberg/bncdn1b1/